# Link Problem DirectX: Linker problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, directx

Ok folks just installed the June DirectX SDK, been reading through the documentation. Set up my visual studio pointing to the correct Lib Include and Executable files using a user variable.

$(DXSDK_DIR) which is set to the SDK file path

I tried a tech demo at random it worked happy days!

Decided to start into the tutorials looked at the first one, decided to open the SLN file and build it to practice a bit of reverse engineering.

Alas no I keep getting this error!

Error 1 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3d10d.lib' Tutorial00 Tutorial00

I have checked the Lib/x86 folder that debug folder is there!!!! I also cleaned and rebuild the solution still no joy!

Thought perhaps it was a problem with my user variable, swapped it out for the direct link.

exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Utilities\Bin\x86

include
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include

lib
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86

Still the same error!

I decided to push that to the side while I tried the 2nd tutorial not it is giving me an error from the same vein.

Error 1 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3d10sdklayers.h': No such file or directory c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\d3d10.h 6676 Tutorial01

the second one seems to be something to do with windows 6 SDK is that not one for mobile development or am I getting confused. I was under the impression that DirectX SDK was self contained and simply needed to be linked to VS compiler. To the ninjas of GameDev, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure what version of visual studio you are using. Sounds like you forgot to add the d3d10d.lib file to the linker settings. If you're using 2010, try adding d3d10d.lib to Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependancies.

The second problem is a misconfiguration with regards to your include paths.